# Exit modal by clicking on background content in React

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using react-bootstrap (documentation: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#modals-props) and am not sure how I can go about closing a modal by clicking on the background.

Currently, I'm closing it through (don't mind the function `onCloseModal`- it pretty much closes the modal):

```
<Modal closeButton={true} onHide={this.onCloseModal.bind(this)}>
    <Modal.Header closeButton={true} onHide={this.onCloseModal.bind(this)}>
    </Modal.Header>
</Modal>
```

There's no documentation on how to close by clicking on the background. I'm sorry I haven't really tried anything, but I've looked everywhere on Stackoverflow and all solutions correspond to jQuery, not React.

Answer (score 0):

It **does has** in the documentation in `props` section named `backdrop`

If you familiar with Bootstrap, you might know the attribute to describe show/hide the modal while clicking into the background action is called `static backdrop`.

So to close a modal by clicking on the background. Try the below code.

```
<Modal {...this.props} backdrop="true">
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-sm">Modal heading</Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Body>
        <h4>Wrapped Text</h4>          
    </Modal.Body>
    <Modal.Footer>
        <Button onClick={this.props.onHide}>Close</Button>
    </Modal.Footer>
</Modal>
```

Note that `...this.props` is [JSX Spread Attributes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html)

Comment: I have `backdrop={true} included` but isn't working.

Comment: because I take a look into react-boostrap and all their modal example have the ability to close modal on clicking the background. Did you change anything ?

Comment: It might have something to do with the ID that I'm assigning each modal. I'll take a look.